# Saving Attachments from Outlook with Python by Message in Subfolder

Tags: python, outlook

I want to save outlook attachments from outlook with the following structure:

attach(on desktop) -->folder(name of subfolder in outlook)-->folder(individual message) --> attachments from message

I am coming across a problem where for some reason all attachments from a subfolder are saving into every message folder instead of just the message folder they belong.

Sorry if my code is redundant I just started learning!

```
import win32com.client as client
import os

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')

path = 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\Attach'
os.chdir(path)

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
inboxfolders = inbox.Folders
inbxcount = inboxfolders.Count

folderlist = []
for x in range(1, inbxcount + 1):
    subfolder = inboxfolders[f'{x}']
    strsub = str(subfolder)
    if 'PRs' in strsub:
        folderlist.append(strsub)
for i in folderlist:
    newfolder = i
    os.makedirs(newfolder)
    sub = inboxfolders[f'{i}']
    messages = sub.Items
    msgcount = messages.Count
    newpath = f'{path}\\{newfolder}'
    for y in range(1, msgcount + 1):
        msgfolder = f'PR{y}'
        os.chdir(newpath)
        os.makedirs(msgfolder)
        path3 = f'{newpath}\\PR{y}'
        for msg in range(1, msgcount + 1):
            message = messages.Item(msg)
            attachments = message.Attachments
            attchcount = attachments.Count
            for attch in range(1, attchcount + 1):
                attachment = attachments.Item(attch)
                sattachment = str(attachment)
                if 'image' not in sattachment:
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path3, sattachment))
                    os.chdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the second for loop iterating over the individual messages. By doing so it eliminated the extra attachments.